Install Crystal reports using Dockerfile in Windows Server 2022 Datacenter
I am installing Crystal Reports version CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_35.MSI.
Added below in Docker file.
RUN ["powershell.exe", "Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET"]  
RUN ["powershell.exe", "Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45"]

And copied oledlg.dll file from another windows VM ro  C:\windows\system32\
Now getting below error:
install64.log:13581:CustomAction SetASPDotNetDllPath returned actual error code 1157 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside 
sandbox)
install64.log:13582:MSI (s) (40:58) [19:17:49:246]: Product: SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework (32-bit) -- Error 1723. There is a
problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  
 Action SetASPDotNetDllPath, entry: SetASPDotNetDllPath, library: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI6F26.tmp
install64.log:13584:Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run.
Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action SetASPDotNetDllPath, entry: SetASPDotNetDllPath, library: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI6F26.tmp
install64.log:14988:Property(S): ErrorDialog = ErrorDialog

